# What am I doing wrong in this recursive function, when returning promise

Tags: javascript, recursion, promise, apache-zookeeper

I need to get the initial `timestamps` of all `znodes` in the `zookeeper`. I am using the `getChildren` method of node-zookeeper-client to do so. I am calling my `getInitialTimeStamp` recursively to traverse along the path. My 
function looks something like this

```
function getInitialTimeStamp(client,path){
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        client.getChildren(
            path,
            function(error,children,stats){
                //if children empty, return
                if (typeof children === 'undefined' || children.length <= 0) {resolve();} 

                timeStamp[path]= {ctime: stats.ctime, mtime: stats.mtime};  
                children.map(child => {
                    getInitialTimeStamp(client,path+'/'+child);
                });
        });
    });
}
```

it is being called like this

```
getInitialTimeStamp(client,path)
    .then(() => {
      console.log(timeStamp);
      console.log("finished");
});
```

The problem is I can not get my `.then()` part to run. I know this is related to returning promise but I do not know what is being done wrong here. Consider my lack of knowledge in promises and `async` programming and provide me with a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are two things wrong .... if children is not empty, you never resolve ... and your children.map may as well be a forEach the way you're using it

So, firstly, you want to resolve something if children has a length, and sescondly, you only want to do so once ALL the `getInitialTimeStamp` of the children is finished, by use of Promise.all

```
function getInitialTimeStamp(client,path){
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        client.getChildren(
            path,
            function(error,children,stats){
                //if children empty, return
                if (typeof children === 'undefined' || children.length <= 0) {
                    resolve();
                } 
                timeStamp[path]= {ctime: stats.ctime, mtime: stats.mtime};  
                // use promise.all to wait for all child timestamps
                Promise.all(children.map(child => getInitialTimeStamp(client,path+'/'+child)))
                // and then resolve this path
                .then(resolve);
        });
    });
}
```

Although that can be cleaned up a bit

```
function getInitialTimeStamp(client, path) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        client.getChildren(path, (error, children, stats) => {
            timeStamp[path]= {ctime: stats.ctime, mtime: stats.mtime};  
            resolve(Promise.all((children||[]).map(child => getInitialTimeStamp(client, path + '/' + child))));
        });
    });
}
```

but still no error checking is done ... i.e. test if `error` is truthy

Comment: Wouldn't this be a lot simpler if `client.getChildren()` were promisified directly.  As this answer stands now, it is missing error handling which pretty much comes for free if you promisify lower levels and then program all the logic using promises.

Comment: how do you promisify the client.getChildren() ?

Comment: @Prasanna - I posted my own answer that both shows you how to promisify `client.getChildren()` and stands on it's own without relying on a higher scoped `timeStamp` variable and provides full error handling.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest this type of implementation that promisifies at a lower level by promisifying  `client.getChildren()`.  That makes it a lot easier to write all your logic using promises and avoids common pitfalls of JaramandaX's implementation such as completely missing error handling and error propagation.

Since promises only resolve to a single value, when promisifying something that passes multiple values to its callback, you have to shoehorn each of the values into an object and resolve with that object.

Also, your implementation seems to be modifying some `timeStamp` global or higher scope variable which seems less than desirable.  So, I've made it so you can optionally pass in an object to start with, but if you don't it will default to an empty object and, in either case, the function will return a promise that will resolve to the object filled with the desired properties, including a `cnt` property so you can more easily see how many are there.

`getInitialTimeStamp()` returns a promise that resolves to an object that contains your desired path properties.

```
// make promisified version that resolves to an object with properties on it
// Depending upon the situation, you might add this to the prototype rather than
// to an instance
client.getChildrenP = function(path) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.getChildren(path, (error, children, stats) => {
            if (error) return reject(error);
            resolve({children, stats});
        });
    });
}

// Returns a promise that resolves to a timeStamp object
// You can optionally pass in an object to be modified or that will default
// to an empty object.  In either case, the returned promise resolves to
// the finished object.
function getInitialTimeStamp(client, path, resultsObj){
    let obj = resultsObj || {cnt: 0};
    obj.cnt = obj.cnt || 0;
    return client.getChildrenP(path).then(results => {
        if (typeof results.children === 'undefined' || children.length <= 0) {
            // return results so far
            return obj;
        }
        ++obj.cnt;
        obj[path]= {ctime: results.stats.ctime, mtime: results.stats.mtime};  
        return Promise.all(children.map(child => {
            getInitialTimeStamp(client,path+'/'+child, obj);
        })).then(results => {
            return obj;
        });
    });
}
```

Usage:

```
getInitialTimeStamp(client, somePath).then(resultsObj => {
     // process resultsObj here
}).catch(err => {
    // process error here
});
```

Comment: I was getting there jfriend00, didn't think about the `resultObj` like that, nice! The only thing that concerns me is the call to `client.getChildren` in `client.getChildrenP` - looks hard coded messy if you had more than one client object (whatever that is!)

Comment: @JaromandaX - Yeah, I just changed `client.getChildren()` to `this.getChildren()`.  That's what I meant for it to be.

Comment: in the original code, `obj[path]= {ctime: results.stats.ctime, mtime: results.stats.mtime};` gets set even if there's no children yet in your code, I think this is skipped if the current result has no children - because of the return - I think you need to move your checking for children logic below this

Comment: @JaromandaX - I did not think that was correct behavior in the OP's original code.  If it was intended, it's a weird side effect since the promise has already resolved, yet the code continues to do some things (including try to call resolve again).  I think the OP meant to `return` after the no children `resolve()`.  I will agree that the OP's intent is not entirely clear.

Comment: I'm also not convinced you would always get the `obj` as the returned promise, wouldn't it be the result of Promise.all, i.e. an array of results?

Comment: @JaromandaX - Yep, fixed that.  It is hard to write perfect code when you can't run it (at least I'm not very good at that).

Comment: `children` would be an array of child "entities", `stats` seems to be the filestats of the current path ... `getChildren` is an ambiguously named function I think!

Comment: @JaromandaX - If the OP cares to participate, we can work on that.  The main reason for my initial post was to show the OP how to promisify `getChildren()`, how to do proper error handling and how to eliminate the assumed `timeStamp` variable (before you had shown any of those) and promote the benefits of promisifying at the lowest level.

Comment: I'm not criticising, well, not in a bad way - as I said, I was getting there after you suggested promisifying the function, but stumbled too much to continue. Just making observations on the answer to try and help the OP :p